# How do I externalize the properties of KAFKA into a different class and call it to the main class?

Tags: java, oop, intellij-idea, apache-kafka, abstraction

I've been trying to use abstraction OOP in order to externalize the properties code, so that I could just call it to the producer class but I can't seem to call it. Here's the code, any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Producer{

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Producer.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Creating Kafka Producer...");

        KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(PropConfigs().prodProps());

        logger.info("Start sending messages...");

        for (int i = 1; i <= AppConfigs.numEvents; i++) {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(AppConfigs.topicName, i, "Message " + i + " Test"), new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        logger.info("\nReceived metadata" + " Topic:" + recordMetadata.topic() + " Partition: " + recordMetadata.partition() + " Offset: " + recordMetadata.offset() + " Time: " + recordMetadata.timestamp() + "\n");
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Error", e);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        logger.info("Finished - Closing Kafka Producer.");
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();

    }
}
```

I would like to transfer all of the props.setProperty to a different class then call it to the producer class. This is what I would like to do:

```
package org.timothy.producer.common;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class PropConfigs {

    public static Properties prodProps(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, AppConfigs.applicationID);
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, AppConfigs.bootstrapServers);
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5");

        return new Properties(props);
    }

}
```

How can I call this to the main class? Or maybe apply it to:
Properties props = new Properties();
KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

Comment: You just need to make `ProdProps()` create a new `Properties` instance and return it, if I'm understanding what you are trying to do correctly.

Comment: I tried that, but then the KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props); from the main class can't recognize the props. Since it's externalized

Answer (score 0):

```
 KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>((new PropConfigs()).prodProps());
```

Or make them static...

```
 KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(PropConfigs.prodProps());
```

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Producer.java

Comment: I updated it, can you check it? I still received an error.

Comment: If you made it static you dont need to set "new"

Comment: Yes, the error is gone. Thank you, but.. when I run the program, it doesn't call the properties from another class. It returns an error "Missing required configuration "key.serializer" which has no default value". This error occurs because  `props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());` is needed.

Comment: (ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
    (ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

Comment: I got an error: 'setProperty(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' in 'java.util.Properties' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer>)'. I tried adding String.valueOf, then run the producer class but it still didn't work. Still Missing required configuration "key.serializer"

Comment: Post an update of what you run ... you are in the right way, to debug look if the propeties are really getting set after the call

Comment: I've updated the code. I think it's not getting set because it doesn't recognize the serializer.

Comment: Why the String.valueOf ?

Comment: It's the autofix if I remove getName()

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/kafka/examples/Producer.java