# How to call the Properties Method and set it into the main class?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, properties, kafka-producer-api

There's no error already, but when I run the program it fails to recognize the serializer which is inside the other class. Here's how it looks like.

```
public class Producer{

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Producer.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Creating Kafka Producer...");

        KafkaProducer<Integer, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(PropConfigs.prodProps());
        // The code above should run and call the PropConfigs (properties of kafka)

        logger.info("Start sending messages...");

        for (int i = 1; i <= AppConfigs.numEvents; i++) {
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(AppConfigs.topicName, i, "Message " + i + " Test"), new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata recordMetadata, Exception e) {
                    if(e == null){
                        logger.info("\nReceived metadata" + " Topic:" + recordMetadata.topic() + " Partition: " + recordMetadata.partition() + " Offset: " + recordMetadata.offset() + " Time: " + recordMetadata.timestamp() + "\n");
                    } else {
                        logger.error("Error", e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        logger.info("Finished - Closing Kafka Producer.");
        producer.flush();
        producer.close();

    }
}
```

Here's the PropConfigs class, where in I put the properties to be called from the main class Producer.

```
public class PropConfigs {


    public static Properties prodProps(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, AppConfigs.applicationID);
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, AppConfigs.bootstrapServers);
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
        props.setProperty(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "5");

        return new Properties(props);
    }

}
```

Whenever I run it, like I said it fails to recognize the properties that I set.

Comment: are you using @EnableConfiguration annotation in the main app class. 
It fails to recognize these properties because you have set them and not telling spring that it needs to be pick these configurations.

Comment: How to do that? What you see up there is the code

Comment: You need to set it 
 props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");

Comment: if possible, please push the entire  project to github so that i can also assist you in debugging.

Comment: @GurkiratSinghGuliani This is not Spring

Comment: What classes did you import in your java application "IntegerSerializer" and the "StringSerializer.class"?

Comment: Related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68492904/how-do-i-externalize-the-properties-of-kafka-into-a-different-class-and-call-it/68493091?noredirect=1#comment121048622_68493091

Answer (score 0):

You mean it fails to recognize the `prodProps` *method*? (You have no custom serializer here). Note: You can have this `return props`

You've not shown your import statements, but make sure the classes are in the same package (and not the default package, or no package)

---

If you really want to externalize the properties, Spring-Boot / Spring-Kafka are commonly used to do so